# How can I make Google prioritize StackOverflow results?

Tags: google-search

I don't want site:stackoverflow.com (that rules out other sites).
I don't want to star stackoverflow.com Google results (that's too manual).

I want to search Google such that any stackoverflow.com result will automatically appear before results from other sites (which then appear below).

Is this possible?

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/is-there-any-way-to-give-more-or-less-weight-to-words-in-a-google-search

Answer (score 11):

I sometimes want to do exactly that, and then I just add the word "stackoverflow" to my search string. This works wonders. Observe:

- [beer stackoverflow](http://www.google.com/search?q=beer+stackoverflow)
- [clothing stackoverflow](http://www.google.com/search?q=clothing+stackoverflow)
- [beautiful sunset stackoverflow](http://www.google.com/search?q=beautiful+sunset+stackoverflow)

Comment: I use this technique to get the MSDN page I'm looking for when researching class methods etc.

Comment: Good job: the first result for 'beautiful sunset stackoverflow' is now this post. http://www.google.com/search?q=beautiful+sunset+stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

[This Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=001706605492879182808:8b-lak46mtw) searches the entire web but emphasizes Stack Overflow results.

Not exactly what you need but close.

Compare: [coinitialize on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=coinitialize) vs. [coinitialize on Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=001706605492879182808:8b-lak46mtw&q=coinitialize)

(Doesn't work for beer or sunset keywords though.)

Comment: From the question, which this solution does not offer: "any stackoverflow.com result will automatically appear before results from other sites".  The first result from your "Custom Search" link above is from MSDN?

Comment: @lance True. On the other hand it uses relevance which is in my opinion better. Anyway, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bigger picture : Google is working on it and you can help them.
Google released a Chrome extension allowing users to blacklist domains and report it to Google servers in order to detect content farms (such as websites which scrape stackoverflow content).

http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/new-chrome-extension-block-sites-from.html

Answer (score 0):

The search engine [DuckDuckGo](https://www.duckduckgo.com) has something they call !-syntax. You can prefix (or infix or postfix) a search query with, for example !stackoverflow or !so and it will search StackOverflow for your query directly from the search bar. It also pulls content for its regular search results directly from the SOFU trilogy so your chances of finding a relevant answer are that much greater.